# ArrayList Unable to return a Struct

Tags: c++, arraylist, struct

Hello all I have been working with my array list and have been using it for a while now and I just tried to use a struct type in my array List in this Program:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "Header.h"

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    struct Params
    {
        int i;
        int j;


    };
    Params p2;
    p2.i = 2;
    p2.j = 3;
    List::ArrayList<Params> p = List::ArrayList<Params>();
    p.add(p2);
    printf("i: %d, j: %d", p.get(0).i, p.get(0).j);

    return 0;
}
```

and this is my ArrayList program:

```
#ifndef ARRAYLIST_H_
#define ARRAYLIST_H_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace List
{

    template <class T>//template - allows the user to choose what type to store in the list
    class ArrayList
    {
    private://private variables
        int length = 1;//sets the length to 1
        T *a1 = (T*)calloc(length, sizeof(T));//allocates enough memory for 1 item

    public://public functions
        ArrayList()
        {//constructor
            //does nothing but you probably already knew that 

        }
        ~ArrayList(){//destructor
            //frees up the memory that a1 is pointing to 
            free(a1);
        }
        inline void add(T item){//adds an item to the list

            if (length != 0)
            {//if length is not equal to 0


                a1 = (T*)realloc(a1, length*sizeof(T));//re-allocates memory 

                a1[length - 1] = item;//adds item to the end of the list
                length++;//adds 1 to the length
            }
            else
            {//else if it is equal to 0


                a1[length] = item;//adds item to the front of the list


            }
        }
        inline void remove(T item){

            if (length != 0)
            {
                length--;//subtracts 1 from the length
                T *b = (T*)calloc(length, sizeof(T));//creates a new pointer to a memory block of size length   
                int idxModifier = 0;//modifies the index so it adds the items to the array in the right places
                int i = 0;//counter/index
                while (i < length){
                    if (a1[i] != item)//if the item at the index of i is not equal to item we want to delete
                    {
                        b[i] = a1[i + idxModifier];

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        idxModifier++;//adds 1 to the index modifier
                        b[i] = a1[i + 1];//adds the next item so we dont add the item back to the array


                    }

                    i++;//adds one to i
                }

                if (count != 0)
                    a1 = (T*)realloc(b, length*sizeof(T));
                else
                    cout << "The item does not exist!" << endl;//lets the user know that item does not exist

                free(b);//frees up the memory that b allocated at the top of the function
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You cannot delete anything because there is nothing in the list" << endl;//lets the user know that there is nothing in the list
            }

        }
        inline T get(int i){//gets the integer at the index of i


            return length != 0 ? a1[i] : NULL;//returns a[i] if the length is not 0, if it is 0 then it returns NULL wich is defined as 0
        }
        inline void set(int i, T type)
        {
            a1[i] = type;//sets whatever is at teh index of i to type
        }
        inline int size(){//gets the size

            return length != 0 ? length - 1 : NULL;//if the length is not equal to 0 then it returns the length-1 , if it is not 0 then it returns NULL
        }
        inline void print(){//prints the list
            if (length != 0)
            {
                cout << "[";//prints the end bracket
                for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++){

                    if (i == 0)//if the index is equal to the beginning of the list
                        cout << a1[0];//print the first item
                    else
                        cout << ", " << a1[i];//prints a comma before the item to seperate the items
                }
                cout << "]" << endl;//prints the end bracket
            }
            else
            {

                cout << "There is nothing in the array to print!" << endl;//lets the user know that the list is empty
            }
        }



    };


};
#endif
```

When I try to run it I get this error: error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'int' to 'main::Params' on line 86
I am completely stuck on this Anyone have any suggestions I have no Idea what to do I think it might be because of the template because it is saying it must return an int but that isn't true because it works with other types so maybe its just with structs. Note: line 86 is the get Function

Comment: Sorry line 86 is the get function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NULL` is a pointer type. Your `T` is not a pointer. You cannot return `NULL` in place of a `T`. You will need to find another way to show that no such entry exists.

```
//                     T     not T
return length != 0 ? a1[i] : NULL;
```

Comment: Wait null is defined as 0 so I'm not getting how that is a pointer type

Comment: When I jump to definition it's defined as ((void*)0) but anyway... even if it were plain 0 as in the standard, even *that* is not of your type `T`. You need to return a type `T`.

Answer (score 3):

If `T` is `Params` then this does not work:

```
inline T get(int i){
   return length != 0 ? a1[i] : NULL;//returns a[i] if the length is not 0
}
```

`NULL` is a macro for `0`, and `Params` does not have a constructor that accepts `0`.

In C++ there is no such thing as a "null object"  (some other languages have that concept, C++ doesn't).

You have to redesign this function to either return a particular value (e.g. `T()`, a default-constructed `T`), or to throw an exception.

You should also check that `i` is within the bounds of the array before doing `a1[i]`; and be aware that using the `malloc` family of functions only works when `T` is a "plain-old-data" type, since it does not call any constructors. This code will be unusable for anything containing a `std::string` for example.

Answer (score 1):

In your get() function NULL equates to 0 which is an int. The compiler is saying that get() may return an int instead of type Params in certain cases. You might instead want to add an assert or an exception to ensure the size is large enough before returning the array value.